# perl: Plotting two separate array

Tags: perl, plot

I have one list called `@V_list`. I created another list that has the same size of the `@V_list` namely `@nn`. Now I want to make a plot `@nn`vs`@V_list`. This is the code I used but I get an error in the `my $gd = $graph->plot(\@nn,\@V_list) or die "Can't plot graph";`. How to get it done?

```
use GD;      
use GD::Graph::lines;

@V_list=(1,2,1,2);
print "@V_list\n";

$size = @V_list;
@nn=1..$size;
print "@nn\n";


my $graph = new GD::Graph::lines( );
my $gd = $graph->plot(\@nn,\@V_list) or die "Can't plot graph";

open(IMG, '>file.png') or die $!;
binmode IMG;
print IMG $gd->png;
close IMG;
```

Comment: What's the error? (See the docs for how to display a specific one)

Answer (score 2):

The `GD::Graph::plot` method [takes a single argument](https://metacpan.org/source/RUZ/GDGraph-1.54/Graph/axestype.pm#L223). The call syntax should be something like

```
$graph->plot( [ \@nn, \@V_list ] )
```

instead of

```
$graph->plot( \@nn, \@V_list )
```